# Adding a new column with words extracted row by row

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to add per each column a new column which contains words satisfying the following condition:

```
df['Names'].str.extractall(r'\b([A-Z][a-z]*)\b')
```

i.e. words having letter capitalized.

The code above extract these words but for all the column, not distinguishing rows.
An example of data is

```
Names
My Lord: come le bande albanesi trafficano i g..
Viaggi di nozze 2020, i dieci eventi imperdibi..
Ma perché vi sto raccontando tutto questo, per Niente
```

The new column should be

```
Names
My Lord: come le bande albanesi trafficano i g..
Viaggi di nozze 2020, i dieci eventi imperdibi..
Ma perché vi sto raccontando tutto questo, per Niente

New
['My', 'Lord']
['Viaggi']
['Ma','Niente']
```

I think I should iterate over the rows. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change to `findall`

```
df['My'] = df['Names'].str.findall(r'\b([A-Z][a-z]*)\b')
```